# Python/Pandas Agregar una nueva columna al dataframe que sume los casos por ciudad

Tags: python, pandas

```
    +---+----------------+---------------------+---------------+
    |   | FECHA_CONTAGIO |        CIUDAD       | CASOS_DIARIOS |
    +---+----------------+---------------------+---------------+
    | 0 |   03-02-2020   |     Bogotá D.C.     |       1       |
    +---+----------------+---------------------+---------------+
    | 1 |   03-06-2020   | Guadalajara de Buga |       1       |
    +---+----------------+---------------------+---------------+
    | 2 |   03-07-2020   |       Medellín      |       1       |
    +---+----------------+---------------------+---------------+
    | 3 |   03-08-2020   |     Bogotá D.C.     |       1       |
    +---+----------------+---------------------+---------------+
    | 4 |   03-08-2020   | Cartagena de Indias |       1       |
    +---+----------------+---------------------+---------------+
    | 5 |   03-09-2020   |     Bogotá D.C.     |       1       |
    +---+----------------+---------------------+---------------+
    | 6 |   03-09-2020   |       Medellín      |       2       |
    +---+----------------+---------------------+---------------+
    | 7 |   03-10-2020   |        Itagüí       |       1       |
    +---+----------------+---------------------+---------------+
    | 8 |   03-10-2020   |        Neiva        |       2       |
    +---+----------------+---------------------+---------------+
    | 9 |   03-10-2020   |       Palmira       |       1       |
    +---+----------------+---------------------+---------------+
```

Tengo la siguiente tabla en Pandas y estoy intentando añadir una nueva columna de Casos Totales, la cual ira sumando los casos por Ciudad. Lo he intentado con un Group By pero no me suma como quiero, es decir, un acumulativo de casos por ciudad.

```
    df_count['CASOS_TOTALES'] = df_count.groupby(['CASOS_DIARIOS'],axis=1).sum().reset_index()
```

Esto es lo que he podido hacer por mi cuenta:

```
    +---+----------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+
    |   | FECHA_CONTAGIO |                     |               |               |
    |   |                |              CIUDAD | CASOS_DIARIOS | CASOS_TOTALES |
    +---+----------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+
    | 0 |     03-02-2020 |         Bogotá D.C. |             1 |             0 |
    +---+----------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+
    | 1 |     03-06-2020 | Guadalajara de Buga |             1 |             1 |
    +---+----------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+
    | 2 |     03-07-2020 |            Medellín |             1 |             2 |
    +---+----------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+
    | 3 |     03-08-2020 |         Bogotá D.C. |             1 |             3 |
    +---+----------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+
    | 4 |     03-08-2020 | Cartagena de Indias |             1 |             4 |
    +---+----------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+
    | 5 |     03-09-2020 |         Bogotá D.C. |             1 |             5 |
    +---+----------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+
    | 6 |     03-09-2020 |            Medellín |             2 |             6 |
    +---+----------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+
    | 7 |     03-10-2020 |              Itagüí |             1 |             7 |
    +---+----------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+
    | 8 |     03-10-2020 |               Neiva |             2 |             8 |
    +---+----------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+
    | 9 |     03-10-2020 |             Palmira |             1 |             9 |
    +---+----------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Me esta colocando el valor del indice, en este ejemplo Bogota deberia irse sumando en cada registro es decir comenzar con uno luego 2, 3 y asi sucesivamente segun los casos diarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que entiendo que necesitas es una suma acumulativa ([`cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html#pandas-dataframe-cumsum))

```
df_count['CASOS_TOTALES'] = df_count.CASOS_DIARIOS.cumsum()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio, en tu respuesta estaba la solucion, la complemente con el comentario de @marmuar y obtuve el resultado que buscaba.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo que buscas es agrupar por ciudad. Tu solución esta cerca. Primero agrupa por ciudad y luego con el dataframe agrupado puedes mergearlo con el original mediante la columna 'CIUDAD'

```
df[['CIUDAD', 'CASOS_DIARIOS']].groupby('CIUDAD').agg('sum')
```

luego:

```
pd.merge <dataframe_original>, <dataframe_agrupado>
```

Espero te sirva.
Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, parte de tu respuesta me ayudo a conseguir el resultado que necesitaba

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias por ambas respuestas pues me sirvieron para solventar mi duda. El codigo que añadi en Pandas fue el siguiente:

```html
df_count['CASOS_TOTALES'] = df_count.groupby(['CIUDAD']).CASOS_DIARIOS.agg('cumsum')
```

Que no es mas que añadir una nueva columna a la tabla y el valor de la misma es la suma acumulada de los casos diarios por ciudad, la suma la realizamos con el GroupBy. El resultado de la tabla es la siguiente:

```html
|   | FECHA_CONTAGIO |              CIUDAD | CASOS_DIARIOS | CASOS_TOTALES |
|--:|---------------:|--------------------:|--------------:|--------------:|
| 0 |     03-02-2020 |         Bogotá D.C. |             1 |             1 |
| 1 |     03-06-2020 | Guadalajara de Buga |             1 |             1 |
| 2 |     03-07-2020 |            Medellín |             1 |             1 |
| 3 |     03-08-2020 |         Bogotá D.C. |             1 |             2 |
| 4 |     03-08-2020 | Cartagena de Indias |             1 |             1 |
| 5 |     03-09-2020 |         Bogotá D.C. |             1 |             3 |
| 6 |     03-09-2020 |            Medellín |             2 |             3 |
| 7 |     03-10-2020 |              Itagüí |             1 |             1 |
| 8 |     03-10-2020 |               Neiva |             2 |             2 |
| 9 |     03-10-2020 |             Palmira |             1 |             1 |
```

Como ven ya me esta acumulando los casos por ciudad. En cuento finalice este ejercicio de visualizacion comparto en este hilo los enlaces al proyecto.

**** Actualizacion al 12/10/2020****

Dejo por aqui el enlace al repositorio en GitHub donde pude finalizar el proyecto que me plantee. Nada del otro mundo, solo estoy aprendiendo.

[Repositorio en GitHub](https://github.com/jjnc2006/Covid19_Colombia)

Comment: Los enlaces que dices y si gustas compartirlos van en esta misma respuesta